# Is there a way to retrieve the owned games list from people that wishlist a game?

Tags: marketing, steam, steamworks

Could anyone versed in Steam API direct me on how I could get insightful data from people that wishlist a game?

The main goal is to know better to what type of players your game appeals to. It seems, you can already get regional information but that's quite broad. Knowing that X% of your wishlister also own a certain title could be really useful, to any gamedev really. Valve has the information for sure, now can we get it as well is an other question.

To a relative extent, having this data for game owners is also interesting, Steamspy already compiles those data in the "related" section.

The documentation as reference, it does not indicate anything on that matter.
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/marketing/wishlist

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I do not believe that Valve exposes individual steam user ids as part of a game's sales and activation reports.  So, you will not be able to correlate with information like "games owned" or "other games wishlisted".  It's common for companies to anonymise user data in this way to protect their users' privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did not imply the contrary. As mentioned these data, shared playerbase between owned games, are already corelated by steamspy. So the real question is why couldn't they be corelated for wishlists ?